# Is the complement of $ww^R$ context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

Identify the language given by $L = \{ x \in (0,1)^* : x \neq ww^R, w \in (0,1)^*\}$. Note: $w^R$ is the reverse of the string $w$.

Closure property can/should be applied only in the cases when the actual language is not specified. Otherwise, you may arrive at wrong conclusions. The language in question is fully specified, so I doubt whether one can directly apply closure property on $ww^R$, which you say, is its complement or vice versa. The given answer is CFL. But I don't seem to have arrived at it satisfactorily.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? The language given is the complement of the language of all even-length palindromes over $\{0, 1\}$. The complement over the universe $\{0, 1\}^*$ is the language of all odd-length words and even-length non-palindromes. If you want a CFG, first make one for odd-length words, then for non-palindromes, and take the union.

Comment: @Patrick87. thanks. u mean L is CFG only? am i right?

Comment: What are you asking for? The language $L$ is context-free, and so is its complement. However, you cannot apply closure properties, since CFL are not closed under complement. Do you need a proof that $L$ is context-free?

Comment: @user1771809 Yes, $L$ is context-free, so there is a CFG which generates it.

Comment: @A.Schulz yes i am looking for a proof. i get confused when i saw a complement of CFG as CFG itself.

Comment: @Patrick87 I think this hint would make up a reasonable answer (with only some elaboration maybe).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show that $L$ is context-free, you can proceed as follows:

Build a push-down automaton $P$ that accepts $L$. $P$ will read the input and put all the read characters on its stack. At some point it guesses (non-deterministically!) that half of the input has been read. Then it reads the remaining input and checks it a against its stack. If $P$ finds a mismatching character it accepts, if it does find not a mismatch, or the guess for the middle of the word was wrong, it rejects.

Comment: This is proof by complementation which doesn't work in case of CFLs. Kindly correct me if i am wrong

Comment: No it is not using "complementation". The PDA I sketched accepts $L$ not $\bar L$. Maybe the non-determinism confuses you. The PDA accepts, if there exists **at least one** accepting run. So you can "guess", when half of the input has been read. If your guess was wrong you reject. But there is one correct guess, if $x\in L$.